# What is Subset Construction in Compiler design?

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, finite-automata

[here is the algorithm :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuCP.jpg)  I am going through the aho,Ulman reference book on Compiler Construction, which explains the subset construction implementation algorithm for NFA to DFA conversion. The explanation there is very brief. I would like to have a more comprehensive understanding of how this process works at a deeper level. Can anyone please suggest me a good reference or a website that could clear these hard to digest concepts?

Comment: What you are not getting actually? and please show some work that you've done and where you are facing problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Compiler Construction` is a great book, but its content is very deep and perhaps difficult to understand (it is designed for a total domain of compilers and many hours are necessary for its total comprension).

**Can anyone please suggest me a good reference or a website that could clear these hard to digest concepts?**

You should try with [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=Compilers%3A%20Principles%2C%20Techniques%2C%20and%20Tools&rlz=1C1RLNS_enCU842CU842&oq=Compilers%3A%20Principles%2C%20Techniques%2C%20and%20Tools&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.179j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

My first implemententation of NFA to DFA was studying for that book.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a name of an algorithm that's used during compiler design.

When you are designing a language, you design the language's lexical structure deploying a tool known as regular expressions. Regular expressions are declarative though, and act as generators, whereas you need something that can act as a recogniser.

For this to happen, you want to arrive to a "machine" that does that, known as a finite automaton. You can generate a non-deterministic finite automaton from a regular expression using an algorithm known as [Thompson's Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction).

The problem with the NFA that you end up with is that it's fairly difficult to emulate programmatically, because of the Non-determinism. For this reason we want to perform another transformation to go from the NFA to a DFA, and that algorithm is known as [Subset Construction](http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node9.html).